# te redireccionó demasiadas veces. Intenta borrar tus cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un proyecto laravel 6.5, en el cual tengo un login hecho con auth. En local funciona, pero al ponerlo en línea me da el error:

> te redireccionó demasiadas veces. Intenta borrar tus cookies. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Si quito el auth deja de redireccionar y me manda a la página. ¿Por qué sucede?

Tengo está función para el auth:

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware(['auth' ,'roles:Administrador,Programador,Dise単ador']);
}
```

Al quitarla me muestra la página, pero si la pongo me reedirecciona

Comment: Es porque tienes un ciclo infinito producto de un error en la lógica del enrutamiento de tu página. Que tienes en el método auth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por sus respuestas, ya lo he logrado.

Fue un error de capa 8.

Es decir, me faltaba un campo en BD que era el de Rol, laravel al no encontrarlo me redireccionaba al login ya que no tenía de donde tomar un rol .